# Chrome Selenium RemoteDriver Locale Issue

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, locale, webdriver

It looks to me that the chrome webdriver forces the locale to en-us when we use it with selenium remotewebdriver. Can anyone confirm exactly how this works and if its possible to force the use of a particular locale (preferrably without delegating to a proxy server)?

Answer (score 0):

(This is taken from an answer on the topic: [Set Chrome's language using Selenium ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18646033/6278).)

You can do it by adding Chrome's [command line switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) "--lang".

Here's how this might look like in Java:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--lang=de-de");
return new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can configure the browser by using capabilities.

for example:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("default_locale", "your_locale");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);  //or RemoteWebdriver(capabilities);
```

I'm not sure that the name of locale capability is "default_locale". Look at the Chrome manual to clarify it.

Comment: Selenium seems to not respect it.

Comment: This sounds good, but I couldn't make it work either. The `default_locale` field is also neither mentioned by [Selenium's page for DesiredCapabilities](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) nor by [ChromeDriver's](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities).