# Set Chrome's language using Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I download ChromeDriver and by defaults the browser language is in English, I need to change it to Spanish, and I have been unable.

```
public WebDriver getDriver(String locale){   
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver/chromedriver.exe");
    return new ChromeDriver();
}

public void initializeSelenium() throws Exception{
    driver = getDriver("en-us")
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do it by adding Chrome's [command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) "--lang".

Basically, all you need is starting `ChromeDriver` with an [ChromeOption](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.java#L105) argument `--lang=es`, see API for details.

The following is a working example of C# code for how to start Chrome in Spanish using Selenium.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--lang=es");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Java code should be pretty much the same (untested). Remember, locale here is in the form language[-country] where language is the 2 letter code from ISO-639.

```
public WebDriver getDriver(String locale){   
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver/chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--lang=" + locale);
    return new ChromeDriver(options);
}

public void initializeSelenium() throws Exception{
    driver = getDriver("es"); // two letters to represent the locale, or two letters + country
}
```

Comment: Has anybody the solution with Appium to test chrome on a mobile device ?

Answer (score 15):

For me, --lang didn't work. It seems to set the language of the first opened tab, all others chrome processes are started with --lang=en-US.

What did work is the following:

```
DesiredCapabilities jsCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", language);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
jsCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Comment: this worked for me using http://www.reliply.org/tools/requestheaders.php to verify.

Comment: For me it also works without the DesiredCapabilities (first and last line).

Answer (score 9):

I had problems with Chrome using US date format (mm/dd/yyyy) instead of the GB dd/mm/yyyy format (even though I had set these in Chrome). Using:

```
options.addArguments("--lang=en-GB");
```

resolved this.

Comment: This worked for me whereas the accepted solution didn't (assuming for English it would be "--lang=en"). It seems it won't work just with the language two-letter code, but one must add the specific "spell" such as "GB".

Edit: using the python variant on [3.141.0](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/3.141.0/)

Answer (score 7):

As of now (Jan 2020 - Chrome  Version 79.0.3945.130) The C# in the accepted answer does not work.

The simplest approach that I can find to work in C# presently:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", language);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 4):

I was trying the same and above listed nothing worked for me, at last I tried the below and it worked:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", "ja-jp,ja");

chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 3):

For me `--lang` also didn't work. I wanted to perform Facebook Login tests with specific language (en-US instead of en-GB) and what I found is that some pages (like Facebook) set interface according to system environment variable `LANG`... So if above answers doesn't work, try changing `LANG` environment variable. Tested on Linux.

Comment: en-US and en-GB do not work for me. Who can help me?

Answer (score 3):

For latest versions below code should work.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--accept-lang=" + locale);
return new ChromeDriver(options);
```

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#accept-lang

Comment: "should work" or "does work"?

Comment: @Eric does work.

Comment: Don't work for me

Answer (score 3):

## From Chrome v117

You need to set `intl.selected_languages` & `intl.accept_languages`,

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", language); //language: "es"
prefs.put("intl.selected_languages", language);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried to solve the problem including

```
chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.add_argument('--lang=es')
```

but it didn't work (I have discovered that isn't necessary).

It works when I changed the locale:

```
locale -a
sudo apt-get install language-pack-es
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

It is es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8 for Spanish. Finally, you have to start a new shell in order to get new env variables (LANG=C.UTF-8 to es_ES.UTF-8)

Comment: Thank you a lot! I had a multi-language website and I needed to get the content in Russian for me. I was passing the --lang argument to Chrome but the website was providing an English content version nevertheless. And only after setting up the locales, everything got working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
website = 'https://e-katalog.lkpp.go.id/id/search-produk?q=' + mylist[i] + 
                                 '&order=relevance&limit=12&offset=' + str(1)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--lang=en");
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

prefs = {
          "translate_whitelists": {'id':'en'},
          "translate":{"enabled":"True"}}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)
time.sleep(10)
driver.get(website)
time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

For people using Selenium with ruby:

I made it work this way:

```
prefs_hash = {
       'credentials_enable_service' => false,
       'profile' => {
           'password_manager_enabled' => false,
       },
       'intl.accept_languages' => 'fr-FR', // <- here
    }

// [...]

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :prefs => prefs_hash, switches: switches, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Answer (score -1):

With latest version of Chrome 122.0.6261.129.
It took almost more than 3 hours to find exact solution. Please use below:

```
options.addArguments("--accept-lang=de-DE");
```

Comment: Learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also, I suggest that you take the [tour] and visit the [help] in order to learn how this website works.