# Selenium WebDriver - changing browser's language on linux

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Opening a browser (google chrome) in a different language through selenium WebDriver works fine when running on PC, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18646033/8165952). But when trying it on linux based systems, or mac-os, it simply doesn't work, and the browser opens on it's default language. I tried using different language code, such as "es_ES" or "es-ES" instead of "es", but nothing helped. Is it a different language code for linux, or is it a different way to manipulate the web driver and not use the "--lang" command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try it but I think you can change the setting from chrome itself as :-

settings -> Lamguages -> Add languages.

Add your language there and give a try. remove other language if required.

For IE refer below link :-

http://www.reliply.org/info/internet/http-accept-lang.html

I have also found a code on same link you shared. Have you tried it?

```
DesiredCapabilities jsCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", language);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
jsCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Source :-

[Set Chrome's language using Selenium ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645205/set-chromes-language-using-selenium-chromedriver)

Comment: Changing through settings is problematic, since I need it to happen automatically - It runs on a remote machine. Regarding the second piece of code - I already tried it. it doesn't help. Browser still opens on English.

Comment: Yes i can understand .. have you tried 2nd apporach by code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you also need to set **prefs > intl > accept_language: en-GB**

`"desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions": {
          "args": ["--lang=en-GB"],
          "prefs": {
            "intl": {
              "accept_languages": "en-GB"
            }
          }
        }
      }`

Answer (score 0):

As you can read at [developer.chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/i18n/#locales-testing), there is a system-dependand way to set language for Chrome. On Linux, a environment variable is required.

I created a Bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

LANGUAGE="en" "/home/plap/projects/pdf-exporter/chromedriver" $*
```

Then I use the path of the script in the place of the path of the real chromedriver executable.

Moreover, since I need to swich language programmatically, I made code to save scripts like that programmatically at each new language required. Indeed the code calls:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", executableFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

in a synchronized block together with `new ChromeDriver(options)`... Yes, it's horrible!