# How to set chrome browser language using java + selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

It does not work chrome browser language setting as below using selenium + Java. Can someone help on this to find reson behind that ?

```
ChromeOptions optionsChrome = new ChromeOptions();
optionsChrome.addArguments("--lang=ja");
driver = new ChromeDriver(optionsChrome);
```

Comment: Below code is working for this issue. But still I have question above asked . I need to know why this is happening     
             
                    ChromeOptions optionsChrome = new ChromeOptions();
                    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
                    prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", browserLocale);
                    optionsChrome.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
                    driver = new ChromeDriver(optionsChrome)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Chrome's language using Selenium ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645205/set-chromes-language-using-selenium-chromedriver)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call option with setExperimentalOption then add the language.
So it should be like:

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--lang=ja");
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Bhumit patel, Thanks for your reply. 
This didn't work for me.  I have added comment for my  post with working solution. But thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation for chrome / firefox

```
  public WebDriver createWebDriver(BrowserType browserType) {
    switch (browserType) {
        case IE:
            return new InternetExplorerDriver();
        case CHROME:
            if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver77.exe");
            }
            if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver77");
            }
            return new ChromeDriver();
        case FIREFOX:
            if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/geckodriver.exe");
            }
            if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/test/resources/drivers/geckodriver");
            }
            return new FirefoxDriver();
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported browserType: " + browserType);
    }
```