# How can i provide language of browser where automated test runs

Tags: windows, selenium, google-chrome, automated-tests

Help me please.
My windows is not english, but my chrome language is english. The problem is when i automate tests and  selenium browser window is open, the language of my selenium window  matches to my windows language but not to my chrome language.

For example: when selenium chrome window is shown and machine types values to the field with suggestion drop down menu. The listed items in the dropdown displayed in my windows language not english.
How can i resolve this proble? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ChromeOptions Provide a way to set the language preferences

Here is an example code in java:-

```
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
      //set language to Spanish
      opt.addArguments("−−lang=es");
      // configure options parameter to Chrome driver
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("https://www.google.com/ ");
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for help. I set up it into my code but it does not work. This is my code. Did i something wrong?

Comment: private static final ChromeOptions chromeOptions;
    static {
        initProperties();

        chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("−−lang=en-us");
        String options = properties.getProperty(PROP_CHROME_OPTIONS);
        if (options != null) {
            for (String argument : options.split(";")) {
                chromeOptions.addArguments(argument);

            }
        }

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    }

Comment: static Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    static boolean isServerRun() {
        return System.getenv("CI_RUN") != null;
    }

    static WebDriver createDriver() {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

        return driver;
    }

Comment: can you try "−−lang=en-US" instead

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645205/set-chromes-language-using-selenium-chromedriver says that there is a desiredCapabilities too which you can set. See if it helps.

Comment: --accept-lang=en-US. This helped me