# Chromedriver lang option in Linux in RobotFramework test

Tags: linux, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I need to start Chromedriver in Finnish language and below RobotFramework keyword works fine in Windows but not in Linux. Is there other solution than to change Linux system language from English to Finnish?

Open Chromedriver

${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys,selenium.webdriver

Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    **--lang=fi**

Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}

Keyword opens Chromedriver in the language which is the system language in Linux, not in Finnish what was expected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645205/set-chromes-language-using-selenium-chromedriver  .. of of the replies there points out that passing just a language part didnt work for them so, i'd try if passing `--lang=fi_FI` and see if that works

Comment: Bah, typo there: fi-FI